# What search tool to use for data living outside of Drupal on the external API?

Tags: views, search

I have an external API with Doctors data. Every doctor item will have:

- Title
- Location ( geolocation address )
- Opening hours
- Short description
- Area of expertise
- Price range

On my Drupal 8 website, I want to be able to utilize a search of Doctors data that will have filters ( location proximity and zip, some checkboxes, and dropdowns ).

I also want to have a google map view with these filters.

I'm looking for the best approach in the selection of search tools. My current options are:

- Search API ( i used it before but never with external data )
- Elastic Search ( still not sure about implementation )
- Introducing Feeds to import data into Drupal and then use Search API
- Something else?

I'm open to any suggestion in terms of implementation and tools selection.

Comment: 1. Wont do unless you have direct access to db. 2. This is not what you think. 3. While possible, I would consider this bad practice. 4. Custom module utilizing the Form API is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the external database credentials, there is a module called [views database connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) that gives you access to an external database in views.

I think it might be possible to configure a view to search through an external database with that module.

UPDATE: Otherwise you might consider creating a rest export view, there are a ton of guides on how to do that, [here](https://www.specbee.com/blogs/how-configure-views-rest-export-drupal-8) is one.

Good luck.

Comment: Since OP mentioned `external API` sounds like he doesn't have, direct access, access to any DB credentials.